# How I can get the size of the all files in python

Tags: python

> Task: get the size of all images in machine who have extension `.png`

My not working decision:

```
import os

file_size = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".png"):
            file_size.append(os.stat(file).st_size)
print(sum(file_size))
```

Output:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Thoughts:

```
file_size.append(os.stat(file).st_size)
```

This code can't find the file to get its attribute, how I can correct this?

thanks

Comment: print the file to see if it's a valid path. If it's not, provide a full path for it so you're using the absolute path instead of a relative path

Comment: @JacobIRR almost helped, i am just a beginner

Comment: Put `try` before and `except FileNotFoundError:` trying to stat the file, and in the except code print the filename, and raise

Comment: have you check what the file is thats causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

The `file` holds the relative filenames and `os.stat` expects its absolute path.
You can simply do

```
file_size.append(os.stat(os.path.join(root, file)).st_size)
```

You can also use `glob` module.

Comment: your decision appears ```FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]``` , but almost working

Comment: @nox174 Yes, because there was a typo (missed typing the rest :D). I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be open to using `pathlib`?

[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a python built-in library just like `os` and `glob`.

If a `FileNotFoundError` is raised for a file having the extension `.png`, it might not be an actual file, but rather a `symlink` pointing to the actual file.

In the event that you would like to sum the size of actual `.png` and avoid accounting for the (negligible) size of `symlink` that are pointing to `.png` files, you could detect `symlink` and avoid any computation based on them. (see below)

```
from pathlib import Path

ROOT_PATH = Path("C:\\")
_BYTES_TO_MB = 1024 ** 2

img_size_lst = []
img_size_mb_lst = []

for path_object in ROOT_PATH.glob("**/*.png"):
    if path_object.is_symlink():
        continue
    else:
        img_size_lst.append(path_object.stat().st_size)
        img_size_mb_lst.append(path_object.stat().st_size / _BYTES_TO_MB)

print(sum(img_size_lst))
```

`img_size_lst` now includes the size, in bytes, of each images.

`img_size_mb_lst` now includes the size, in mb, of each images.

Answer (score -1):

```
import glob
import os

png_files = glob.glob("*.png")   # get png files
each_png_file_size = []
for file in png_files:
    each_png_file_size.append(os.stat(png_files[0]).st_size)  # get the size of each file
files_size = sum(each_png_file_size)
print(files_size)  # print total size of all png files in bytes
```